# How to avoid html tags in Google search summary

Tags: php, html, google-search, javascript, jquery

I am using CKEditor to let people describe their organization with all the styles and fonts. So when it saves in the database its like `<` gets saved as `&gt` and rest all you know for the html tags. When I populate this page for public view I convert the `&gt` and `&lt` to html tags so no issue in displaying too. But the thing noticed recently is when I search the same profile in google I can see `<strong>` `<p>` such kind of tags their. Searched Google and Stack Overflow to solve the same but didn't help. Is their any feasible solution?

Sample example of how content from CKEditor stores in table is `&lt;p&gt;
   Privacy Policy&lt;/p&gt;` is this. I convert this on web page at load time to html tags so that people see the style and fonts what they wanted. But the Google search summary shows html tags(unwanted). [The link for sample view of problem](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=channelier%20global%20bathfitting)

Comment: Are you using ckeditor on your own site or as part of a pre-built CMS? I'm not sure how ckeditor works on the back end but you shouldn't be saving the HTML entities (eg. `&gt;`) in the database - this is what's ultimately causing the problems and making it harder to work with. Only when you display this content in an HTML context (ie. "populate this page for public view") should you be converting to HTML entities.

Comment: I am using OpenCart which is a MVC for ecommerce kind of sites.

Comment: but i do use a jquery script on page load for replacing all the &gt and &lt before  showing it to public. So when someone clicks on the google link the page shows fine.But I will do try and tell @w3d how your suggestion helped. Thanks!

Comment: That's the thing, you should never (or at least very rarely) have to manually convert HTML entities back into the real characters - especially not with JavaScript (jQuery). And that's the problem here... you have large code blocks that are encoded with HTML entities (so they are essentially just plain text) and this what Google has picked up in the search results - when this is displayed as-is on the webpage (ie. in the search results) the HTML entities are converted back to the real characters for display, which is what you are seeing.

Comment: Actually, looking at the content (which consists of large blocks of HTML entity encoded text - which should simply be raw HTML) it doesn't look like you should be encoding/decoding anything. The text (HTML) should be stored as-is in the database and simply output directly to the page. (Although if this is user submitted content - although it doesn't look like it, since this is your actual page content (maybe entered by an Admin?) - then this would have other security implications.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23008/discussion-between-preeti-maurya-and-w3d).

Comment: @PreetiMaurya why dont you remove all html tags from google's meta tags??

Comment: @NishantSolanki Sorry I am new to this stuff! How to remove all html tags from google's meta tags? And will this work when my user's keep increasing and their information page keeps increasing with the same pace?

Comment: @PreetiMaurya Are you using something like `<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />` for google search???

Comment: No. And i don't think it is connected to that.

Comment: @PreetiMaurya so you are saying that you are not even using google search meta tags for google search? Try using them,. may be they will replace the current content coming in google search... :) https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Comment: @PreetiMaurya please let me know if that helped you solving the your problem

Comment: Yup sure @NishantSolanki

Comment: @NishantSolanki: They aren't "_google's_ meta tags", they are simply "meta tags". But even if the meta description was set correctly this would not necessarily solve the problem - Google does not always use the meta description in the search results. (Incidentally the meta description should obviously not contain any tags and any special HTML characters must be entity encoded.)

Comment: @w3d sorry, **i meant meta tags supported by google**, and i think google is not able to find the supported meta tags and it is showing html content, but if OP uses the meta tags than there are possible chances that google's crawler will give priority to the content used in meta tags for search results

Comment: You should be doing the server side if you have to do such.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `<meta name="description">` you need to add this to your html page `<head></head>`.

I use two PHP function for my content description before adding content to the 
`<meta name="description">` I use `htmlspecialchars_decode()`for skipping html characters, for more information about this function [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php).

Use `strip_tags()` for skipping html tags, for more information about this function [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

In the end result in this case is

```
$noramlText = htmlspecialchars_decode(strip_tags($htmlText), ENT_COMPAT);

<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $normalText; ?>">
```

I'm sorry for bad English